# Regex Matching in Python 2.7 for HTTP GET Headers

Tags: regex, python-2.7, http, get

I am trying to form a regular expression that will match as follows:

- One or more of any character except a colon or space, that then ends with a colon
- Followed by a space
- Followed by one or more number of any character except a colon or space
- Followed directly by `/r/n`

As specified above, this is for HTTP GET requests so any of the following would work:

- Host: www.stackoverflow.com/r/n
- a-b-sads&^*@hgsdafAS&FTD: sjal;dfh9S^&*D^F&*(SDfsdgafs/r/n

and the following would not:

- Host : www.stackoverflow.com
- H:o:s:t: www.stackoverflow.com
- Host: www.:::stackoverflow.com
- Host: www.stackoverflow.com/n

I am currently using `re.compile(r"^.{1,}: .{1,}[/r/n]$")` but am not sure how to exclude colons from certain subsets of the string.

**EDIT:** I believe what I want to start with is `^` to signify the beginning of a string. Then, I want one or more number of *any character except a colon* so `.{1,}`, but I am not sure how I would exclude colon from this list. Then I want a colon and a space, so just `:`, and then any character except a colon `.{1,}` with the same problem as before of excluding colons. Finally, I want it to end with `[\r\n]$`. This still does not seem to work, even if I exclude the no colon character requirement. So something like `^.{1,}: .{1,}\r\n$`, but I still need to figure out how to exclude colons.

Comment: why does the first "Host : www.stackoverflow.com" not match your requirements?

Comment: @VeltzerDoron Because it goes Host *space* : *space* where the first space should not be present.

Comment: So, you want to exclude spaces from the first string as well, or just before the colon?

Comment: @Veltzer Doron Ah yes, the first string up to the colon should exclude spaces and colons. Then a colon followed by a single space, and then a second string that excludes spaces and colons that ends with /r/n.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. {1,} is simply +
2. excluding colons is done by [^:]*
3. If you want to exclude spaces and colons, use [^ :]
4. catching end of string with $ following \r\n seems strange to me, it means a single string ending with an eoln and nothing after it (also I hope you know about the difference between unix and windows regarding this)
5. Also: eoln is \r\n, putting something in square brackets means either of the characters contained will match which is not what you need

In total, the following should work

`^([^ :]+): ([^ :]+)$`

giving Host in group 1 and the url in group 2

Test it [here](https://regex101.com/)

Comment: Ok, it makes sense now what exactly I was doing wrong. Thank you for your help.